# 'Like' application API

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm facing a case that you probably already heard about. It doesn't look like possible, but anyway i feel like i have to ask.

So here is the thing.
Consider you have a mobile application, let say an iPhone App.
Consider you have product pages online. Those pages have a facebook like button (social plugin 'Like').

From the app, I do want to "Like on Facebook" (picture 1) - better from a native button - with this i would like the authentication to be the same way FBConnect do (open the Facebook App or facebook.com on Safari Mobile).
Then, once authentication is done, the one application I'm working on should be back and have the "Like on Facebook" button disabled.

Is there any way, with the API, of doing such a thing ? Basically, it would be "use the like application from an app".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API available to add likes to Facebook pages or URLs - only to posts, photos, etc.